# PDF reports with embedded fonts subsets

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

I am looking for a reports in PDF with embedding font subsets. Please recommend a useful library. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Fast Report.Net. This is the best choice for me.

Comment: Can I save PDF in Fast Report without preview?

Answer (score 0):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

[Emebedding fonts in iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts)

Comment: Thank you! But reports in iTextSharp are more difficult than in reporting library.

Answer (score 0):

I was also going to recomend iTextSharp but saw your comment saying it is difficult. If ease of use is also important please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) (disclaimer, I'm the CTO there). It is very easy to use (design reports in Word, Excel, or PowerPoint) and will generate PDF with embedded fonts.